# Building Zetacoin on FreeBSD: undefined reference to `Shutdown()

Tags: c++, boost, freebsd, bitcoin

I am trying to build zetacoin on FreeBSD 9.2 but I have come across a compiler error that I can't figure out.

```
obj/bitcoind.o: In function `AppInit(int, char**)':
/root/zetacoin/work/zetacoin-zetacoin-5eed859/src/bitcoind.cpp:43: undefined reference to `Shutdown()'
/root/zetacoin/work/zetacoin-zetacoin-5eed859/src/bitcoind.cpp:57: undefined reference to `HelpMessage()'
/root/zetacoin/work/zetacoin-zetacoin-5eed859/src/bitcoind.cpp:102: undefined reference to `AppInit2(boost::thread_group&)'
/root/zetacoin/work/zetacoin-zetacoin-5eed859/src/bitcoind.cpp:121: undefined reference to `Shutdown()'
obj/bitcoind.o: In function `DetectShutdownThread(boost::thread_group*)':
/root/zetacoin/work/zetacoin-zetacoin-5eed859/src/bitcoind.cpp:12: undefined reference to `ShutdownRequested()'
/root/zetacoin/work/zetacoin-zetacoin-5eed859/src/bitcoind.cpp:17: undefined reference to `ShutdownRequested()'
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was indeed building correctly and failing during the test target.  Zetacoin currently does not have a test suite.

Problem solved.